# Different real roots polynomial, roots of $P'+aP$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

> Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real roots $t_1<t_2\ldots<t_n$. Show that $P' + aP$, with $a\in\mathbb{R}$, has only real roots.

Is easy to conclude if $a=0$, by Rolle's theorem. But I can't see what to do if $a\neq0$. Any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Use the function $f(x) = e^{ax}P(x)$ and see that its derivative is $f'(x) = e^{ax}\{P'(x) + aP(x)\}$.

> Since $f(x)$ has $n$ distinct real roots we get $(n - 1)$ distinct roots of $f'(x)$ and so of $P' + aP$ and since this is a degree $n$ polynomial there is only one more root and it has to be real as complex roots appear in pairs.